# Paste fixed string without using clipboard (i.e. regular copy & paste)

Tags: 20.04

I need to paste a fixed string (`<br>`) often. Therefore I created the following keyboard shortcut to copy the text into the clipboard:

```
sh -c 'echo "<br>" | xclip -rmlastnl -selection clipboard'
```

Works well. But that's still too much work. Therefore: Would it be possible to paste `<br>` directly via a separate keyboard shortcut? The perfect solution would be something that doesn't overwrite the current content of the clipboard.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‣ If your command works well, you can directly assign it to a keyboard shortcut in "Settings" - "Keyboard".

‣ Better perhaps is to use `xdotool` to directly type the string whenever you press a shortcut key. `xdotool` can "type", so you could make it type directly instead of using the clipboard.

Start with a command like this:

```
xdotool keyup ctrl+shift+b type \<br\>
```

This makes `xdotool` type `<br>`. The `\` is an escape string, indicating to bash that it should not interpret the characters `<` and`>` as the redirection symbols they normally represent.

There is an additional trick included here: the `keyup` command. In the example, I assume that you will assign the command to the hotkey <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>. You will be hitting that key combination to trigger the command. The keys may in most cases still be pressed while `xdotool` adds the typing. That may not lead to the expected outcome. The `keyup` statement is used to simulate releasing these keys before the typing happens. Change the keys specified after `keyup` to the actual shortcut key you use.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried `sh -c 'sleep 0.1; xdotool keyup ctrl+shift+b type \<br\>'` and it works as keyboard shortcut, but (for me in Ubuntu 20.4) this has a delay of ~0.5 sec (i.e. it's not the `sleep 0.1`) and it seems to be weirdly CPU intensive (CPU fan immediately jumps noticeably into action). But thanks to you I just rediscovered `AutoKey` and that works without any problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have tested the command also on a hotkey, and it worked OK and fast without a sleep command. Fortunately, indeed, Autokey seems back on track since a few years. I used it before, but at some moment, it broke and since then I stick with my own scripts based on xdotool for snippets. Works very well for me (one you know the tricks and tuned it).